# How do I include font-awesome-sass gem in Jekyll project

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

So I have a Jekyll project and I installed the font-awesome-sass gem from here:  https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass

It only has instructions for using it within a rails project, but how might one use a gem outside of rails?

I put a simple file in my _plugins folder that has the single line:

```
require 'font-awesome-sass'
```

From the readme, I glean that the gem will generate a scss file and I need to tell it where to put a font-awesome.scss file.  How do I go about doing that?  Any direction or resources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the latest Jekyll can already handle `sass`, `scss` and `coffee` files "out of the box", see [this link](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/), so you may not need to use your specific gem.

But if you really want to use that particular gem, you can do what I used to use before I discovered that Sass conversion was built in already. I pulled this simple `sass-converter.rb` file in `_plugins`, which I got from a *GitHub* page (but I don't remember which one anymore, sorry). It requires the plain `sass` gem, but I assume you could do something similar with your specific gem:

```
module Jekyll
  # Sass plugin to convert .scss to .css
  #
  # Note: This is configured to use the new css like syntax available in sass.

  require 'sass'

  class SassConverter < Converter
    safe true
    priority :low

    def matches(ext)
      ext =~ /scss/i
    end

    def output_ext(ext)
      ".css"
    end

    def convert(content)
      begin
        puts "\nPerforming Sass Conversion."
        # put your own call and options here:
        engine = Sass::Engine.new(content, :syntax => :scss, :load_paths => ["./"], :style => :expanded)
        engine.render
      rescue StandardError => e
        puts "\n!!! SASS Error: " + e.message
      end
    end
  end
end
```